# SQL, Listar numero números que não estão na sequencia da tabela

Tags: sql, mysqli

Como eu poderia listar números que estão faltando para completar a sequencia de de números determinada coluna da minha tabela?

veja o link para visualizar minha base de testes: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d124553/1

Veja abaixo meu select para trazer a sequencia: observe que a coluna 'cod_setor' não lista o numero 4:

```
SELECT id_item_inventario,cod_setor FROM item_inventarios WHERE id_inventario='68'
```

*Resultado da query:*

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: cod_setor existe em outra tabela? pode fazer um join para isso

Comment: Os números que faltam para completar a sequencia não existe em nenhuma outra tabela.
A unica coisa que eu tenho para relacionar é um numero de setor inicial e setor final Exemplo: 'setor inicial =1' e 'setor final =5'.

Comment: *"Como eu poderia listar números que estão faltando"* se não estão em nenhuma tabela não daria pra listar (select). Você pode criar uma tabela temporaria com todos os valores possíveis, por exemplo entre 1 e 9999999, e usando um join listar só os que não existem na tabela "item_inventarios"

Comment: Precisa ser no SQL isso? Acredito que no código ficaria mais fácil

Comment: Gostaria de executar em SQl. mas se for muito complexo vou ter que implementar em php.